# How do I split and comma-delimit names?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this column

```
NAME
John Stephenson
James Martin
Anna Corelia
```

How I can select this column to this?

```
NAME
Stephenson, John
Martin, James
Corelia, Anna
```

Comment: Do any of your names have middle initals or two part last names like "Rip Van Winkle" or is it always two parts split by a white space?

Comment: What does this have to do with trimming?

Comment: do you mean split, substring and move the values around rather than trim?

Comment: @JiggsJedi - Always a two parts split by a whit space.

Comment: What do you want to do if you have a "last name" with 2 names in it? Or if you have an entry with a middle name?

Comment: You want to substring and concat values not trim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way

```
;with test(name) as (
    select 'John Stephenson' union all
    select 'James Martin' union all
    select 'Anna J. Corelia' union all
    select 'BOBBYTABLES'
)
select
case when charindex(' ', name) = 0 then name  
else right(name, charindex(' ', reverse(name)) - 1) + ', ' + substring(name, 1, len(name) - charindex(' ', reverse(name))) end
from test


(No column name)
Stephenson, John
Martin, James
Corelia, Anna J.
BOBBYTABLES
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question has nothing to do with `TRIM()` function. Probably you are trying to get something like below using `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` function of `SQL Server` and concatanating them with `,`

```
select right('John Stephenson',(len('John Stephenson')-charindex(' ','John Stephenson')))
+ ', ' + left('John Stephenson',(charindex(' ','John Stephenson') - 1))
```

which will result in

```
Stephenson, John
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution including how I got the final output column.

This will handle three part names, like "Rip Van Winkle", also names with no white space and will strip (trim) any leading/trailing white space from the names.

```
DECLARE @NAMES TABLE (NAME NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @NAMES (NAME) VALUES ('John Stephenson'),('James Martin'),('Anna Corelia'),('Rip Van Winkle'),('Sally')

SELECT *, 
       CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME))) [SpaceLocation],
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME)))>0 THEN RIGHT(LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME)), LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME)))-CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME)))) END [LastName],
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME)))>0 THEN LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME)),CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(RTRIM(LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME)))))-1) END [FirstName],
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME)))>0 THEN RIGHT(LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME)), LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME)))-CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME)))) + ', ' +LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME)),CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME)))-1) ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME)) END [FinalOutput]
FROM @NAMES
```

Comment: It does not handle three part names correctly.`Rip Van Winkle` turns to `Van Winkle, Rip`

Comment: That is correct.  Van is not part of the first name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT substring(NAME+', '+NAME,charindex(' ',NAME)+1,len(NAME)+1) FROM MyTable
```

This also turns `"Rip Van Winkle"` into `"Van Winkle, Rip"`

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4a53/1)**

Answer (score -1):

There is no a single trim function but you can

```
 select   ltrim(rtrim(colname)) from tablename
```

which will TRIM both sides.

but what you need is:

```
declare @name varchar(300) ='Stephenson John';
Select  

Substring(@name, 1,Charindex(' ', @name)-1) +
', '  +
Substring(@name, Charindex(' ', @name)+1, LEN(@name))
 as name
```

Sorry I miss post

Comment: sorry i miss post :'c you are so fast